# how to use cellreferences with 2 rows with apache poi

Tags: java, apache-poi

I need to do these validations, but when i trie to get the value from row b4, i get error, because the Row param get the row from cellReferenceC3 "row 3", but i need from row 3 and 4, c3 and b4

```
Row row = sheet.getRow(cellReferenceC3.getRow());
```

private boolean validaLinha(InputStream arquivoCancelamento) throws IOException{

```
        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(arquivoCancelamento);
        wb.setForceFormulaRecalculation(true);
        Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
        FormulaEvaluator evaluator = wb.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
        String celulaB3 = "N\u00FAmero do Cart\u00E3o ";
        String celulaC3 = "N\u00FAmero Pedido";
        String celulaD3 = "Motivo de Cancelamento";
        String celulaE3 = "Observa\u00E7\u00E3o";
        String celulaB4 = "";
        boolean val = false;

        CellReference cellReferenceB3 = new CellReference("B3");
        CellReference cellReferenceC3 = new CellReference("C3");
        CellReference cellReferenceD3 = new CellReference("D3");
        CellReference cellReferenceE3 = new CellReference("E3");
        CellReference cellReferenceB4 = new CellReference("B4");

        Row row = sheet.getRow(cellReferenceC3.getRow());


        Cell cellB3 = row.getCell(cellReferenceB3.getCol());
        Cell cellC3 = row.getCell(cellReferenceC3.getCol());
        Cell cellD3 = row.getCell(cellReferenceD3.getCol());
        Cell cellE3 = row.getCell(cellReferenceE3.getCol());
        Cell cellB4 = row.getCell(cellReferenceB4.getCol());


        if ((cellReferenceB3!=null && celulaB3.equals(cellB3.getStringCellValue() ))
                &&  (cellReferenceC3!=null && celulaC3.equals(cellC3.getStringCellValue() ))
                && (cellReferenceD3!=null && celulaD3.equals(cellD3.getStringCellValue() ))
                && (cellReferenceE3!=null && celulaE3.equals(cellE3.getStringCellValue() ))
                && (cellReferenceB4!=null)
```

Comment: Use an [AreaReference](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/util/AreaReference.html) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not like this, i.e. having two references, one to row 3, and one to row4?

```
        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(arquivoCancelamento);
        wb.setForceFormulaRecalculation(true);
        Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
        FormulaEvaluator evaluator = wb.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
        String celulaB3 = "N\u00FAmero do Cart\u00E3o ";
        String celulaC3 = "N\u00FAmero Pedido";
        String celulaD3 = "Motivo de Cancelamento";
        String celulaE3 = "Observa\u00E7\u00E3o";
        String celulaB4 = "";
        boolean val = false;

        CellReference cellReferenceB3 = new CellReference("B3");
        CellReference cellReferenceC3 = new CellReference("C3");
        CellReference cellReferenceD3 = new CellReference("D3");
        CellReference cellReferenceE3 = new CellReference("E3");
        CellReference cellReferenceB4 = new CellReference("B4");

        Row row3 = sheet.getRow(cellReferenceC3.getRow());

        Cell cellB3 = row3.getCell(cellReferenceB3.getCol());
        Cell cellC3 = row3.getCell(cellReferenceC3.getCol());
        Cell cellD3 = row3.getCell(cellReferenceD3.getCol());
        Cell cellE3 = row3.getCell(cellReferenceE3.getCol());

        Row row4 = sheet.getRow(cellReferenceB4.getRow());
        Cell cellB4 = row4.getCell(cellReferenceB4.getCol());
```